# Pass data form Express.js to Jade view in specific way

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm using express.js and jade/pug for views.
I want to dynamically create slider, each slider from 2 photos.

Since now I rendered each file one after one, like this:

```
router.get('/:id', (req,res) => {
let query = {authUserName: req.user._id}
  Photo.find(query, (err, photos) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else{
      res.render('user_photos', {
        user: req.user,
        photos: photos,
        title: req.user.userName + ' photos'
      })
    }
  });
});
```

and:

```
block content
  h1.userPhotos #{user.userName} photos
  #imagesContainer
    each photo in photos
      .imgContainer
        .image
          a(href='/photos/edit/'+photo._id)
            img.edit-photo(src='/' + photo.path)
```

It is the way I'm displaying slider right now:

```
block content
  h1.userPhotos #{user.userName} photos
  #imagesContainer
    img(src='/uploads/photos/1.jpg')
    img(src='/uploads/photos/2.jpg')
```

Then I'm using 3rd party library for that.

Photos I want to display are stored in `photos` directory with names:

```
photo_id5a1e9bd71f49972e2471a80f_nr28.png
photo2_id5a1e9bd71f49972e2471a80f_nr28.png
```

Every two photos for one slider have the same names, except the `photo/photo2` prefix.
Next two photos will have names like this:

```
photo_diffrentID_nextNumber.png
photo_idLikeAbove_numberLikeAbove.png
```

So my question is how can I do this?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question and your problem. `It is the way I want to display slider`, then why don't you? You wrote the correct code underneath this statement. `I'm using 3rd party library for that` for what? Which library? `photo_idLikeAbove_numberLikeAbove` above, which line? The line _right_ above this one, or the paragraph above? `how can I do this?` Do what? Sorry... I'm lost

Comment: Sorry. I edited question, there should be `I'm displaying slider right now`. It is hard coded. I want to do it in loop for for example 100 pairs of photos. I don't know how. Like above means line above. Thank you.

Comment: Uh, so, basically, if I understand correctly, you have pairs of photos? Like, a long list of photos, but they go 2 by 2 in that list? And you want to create one slider for each pair of photos?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Why didn't you say so :) I don't use Pug so I'm not really sure how to do it, but I guess you'll have to make a loop that goes 2 by 2, not one by one. Something like `while( i<photos.length){ (display photo[i] then display photo[i+1]); i+=2 }`

Comment: I will try at home and let you know :)